# Xcode: iPhone 5 App Launch image not updating

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, cordova

I am building an app with Cordova/PhoneGap and have added my app Launch Images in Xcode.

However, when testing on my iPhone 5 the launch image does not appear to be changed - it still shows the default Cordova version.

I am running Xcode version 4.6.2 which I believe is the latest and it does have a space for the 4" iPhone 5 image - its just not appearing when I test on the phone.

The image Ive used is 640x1136 as specified in the documentation.

Would anyone know why this is occurring?

Thanks!

EDIT:

I have noticed a warning that appears:

```
/Users/me/Documents/Cordova27/app/app/Classes/AppDelegate.m:80:25: 'useSplashScreen' is deprecated: Deprecated in Cordova 2.5. Add/Remove the SplashScreen plugin instead of setting this property.
```

It is referring to this line in the AppDelegate.M file:

```
#endif
    self.viewController.useSplashScreen = YES;

    // Set your app's start page by setting the <content src='foo.html' /> tag in config.xml.
    // If necessary, uncomment the line below to override it.
    // self.viewController.startPage = @"index.html";

    // NOTE: To customize the view's frame size (which defaults to full screen), override
    // [self.viewController viewWillAppear:] in your view controller.

    self.window.rootViewController = self.viewController;
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];

    return YES;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

1. Clean and then build.
2. Delete the app from simulator/device
3. Ensure your image file name should be Default-568h@2x.png
4. Resolution should be exactly 640x1136.

Comment: Thanks but still nothing. I did however see an error whilst doing this which I have added above

Comment: Comment out the line in AppDelegate.m


from 
self.viewController.useSplashScreen = YES;

to 
//self.viewController.useSplashScreen = YES;

for more info:
http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.5.0/cordova_splashscreen_splashscreen.md.html#Splashscreen

Comment: This worked for me.  I think it may have been deleting the app from the simulator.

Comment: Great, cleaning and rebuilding the solution made it work for me. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

you need to add -568h@2x suffix to your image file, so it would look like:

default-568h@2x.png

then you drag from finder and drop it into launch images section of the target summary.

Answer (score 0):

I have had similar problems when changing the launch image.

Try cleaning your build and the build folder  `(cmd+option+k and cmd+option+shift+k)`

You could also try clearing out the "DerivedData"

> (/Users/youruser/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData)

folder and "folders" `(/private/var/folders)`.

Answer (score 0):

Basically when you will run on iOS device the names are case sensitive. So your image file name should be Default-568h@2x.png and the resolution should be exactly 640x1136.

Answer (score 0):

Update the images in `<your_project_name>/Resources/splash`